# Should I partition or format a disk before replacing a FAULTED disk in a ZFS pool?

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux

I recently had a FAULTED disk in a ZFS pool and wanted to replace it. I simply put the disk in and let it resilver. Afterwards, I noticed the disk was partitioned differently than the other disks and I could not boot anymore. This turned out to be a GRUB issue and I needed to re-install GRUB.

But the question is, should I partition the disks the same way or just disregard?

The pool is a RAID-Z2 pool with 6x 6TB disks, all same brand and model.

Comment: Putting the root filesystem on ZFS (on Linux) is not yet production ready and probably never will be.

Comment: This is how Proxmox does it though...